# Scraping dialogue from meeting minutes stored on public website

Tags: javascript, jsp, web-scraping

I am currently trying to extract a series of discussions that my local parliament had conducted.

I have extracted over 4000+ unique URL's to each documented discussion. The last missing step now is to scrape the metadata for each conversation and split the text according to who spoke and in the right order.

My ideal data would be :
Row 1 Date, Title, Speaker A's name, What he said
Row 2 Date, Title, Speaker B's name, what she said
...

[Example URL 1](http://sprs.parl.gov.sg/search/topic.jsp?currentTopicID=00005836-WA&currentPubID=00005830-WA&topicKey=00005830-WA.00005836-WA_3%2Bbudget%2B)
[Example URL 2](http://sprs.parl.gov.sg/search/topic.jsp?currentTopicID=00005370-WA&currentPubID=00005363-WA&topicKey=00005363-WA.00005370-WA_2%2Bid-fd6401fe-6391-491f-9ac9-48cfc52daa40%2B)

**What I have tried:**
Webscraper.io Has been the most promising. However, it scrapes in random order and thus my speeches are all jumbled up.

iRobot and Import.io Doesnt seem to be able to pick up Javascript

Cloudscrape barely got it, because of the messy tags. The dialogue starts with question tag, answer tag for the first two dialogues. Further debate are all appended using the topic tag. (Whoever designed the system did'nt think of more than one 1 questiona and 1 reply)

**Background:**
I am thinking to parse this back into SQL so that I could visualize and do metrics for the data. I have tried asking the owners before but they don't have the raw data ready. I have taken a peek into the structure of the data and it is really better to just scrape it rather than get access to the messy source.

I have tried looking into Beautifulsoup but I am still utterly lost at how I should start/ whether it is the right tool in the first place.

Comment: The javascript on the website will be taking too long to load, and will timeout the request for most data extraction platforms.

The chances are you will have to render the page using a JS rendering tool, wait a few seconds, and only then extract the data you need.

If you are trying to do this at scale and regularly the costs may soon add up to be quite substantial in terms of processing and rendering costs. Good luck to you though :)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a crawler a while back, this is a bit overkill as it calls beautiful soup twice but it was the only way i could find to pull all the visible text from a page.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
import urllib
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
import re

def get_all_words(page): # gets all visible text on webpage
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
    for element in soup(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment)):
        element.extract()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(str(soup), "html.parser")
    soup = soup.findAll(text=True)
    visible_texts = filter(visible, soup)
    words = []
    for x in visible_texts:
        for wrd in x.split():
            valid = re.match('^[\w-]+$', wrd) is not None
            if len(wrd) > 1 and valid:
                words.append(str(wrd.encode("UTF-8")))
    return words

def visible(element):
    if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', '[document]', 'head', 'title','link',',','.',' | ']:
        return False
    return True

page = urllib.urlopen('http://www...').read()
print get_all_words(page)
```

might be of some use to you